# How many Number of exceptions in a single catch clause in Java?

Tags: java, exception

From Java 7 we can catch multiple exceptions in a single catch clause like below.

```
try { 
  // Your code here.
} catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException |
            NoSuchFieldException e) { 
  // Handle exception here.
}
```

How many number of exceptions can be caught in a same catch clause?
Is there any limit ?
What is the best practice on number of exceptions in same catch ?

Answer (score 2):

About a general catch, not distinghuishing individual exceptions.

You can use base class exceptions, like `IOException`, and drop its child exceptions, like `EOFException`. This is a good practice as all (possibly future) child exceptions are catched. This principle also holds for a `throws IOException` clause.

Run time exceptions, when not treated in their own `catch`, should only be catched, maybe in the same way, as `RuntimeException`, when it is a catch-all. (One should not catch always all.)